# Converting from Backbone habits to Meteor: trigger events

Tags: meteor, backbone-events, eventtrigger

In Backbone, if you want to talk between models you usually do it throug events. For example, if `sayHi()` should be done in a `Friend` model rather than in a `Stranger` model, you'd do the following.

inside Stranger

```
Friend.trigger("callSayHi");
```

inside Friend

```
this.listenTo("callSayHi", function() {
  sayHi();
}
```

I wanted to do the same in Meteor and I thought using a `Session` var fitted.

inside Stranger

```
Session.set("callSayHi", true);
```

inside Friend

```
if (Session.get("callSayHi") {
  sayHi();
}
// Session.set("callSayHi", false); <-- PROBLEM
```

Let's leave out the problem of scoping (using a `ReactiveVar` is better, etc.) here. The problem is, to handle this situation more appropriately, I would have to set the session var at the end to `false` again but that would invoke `sayHi()` event infinitely. I feel like this kind of situation is very common. What's the Meteor way of handling it?

Might be related:
https://forums.meteor.com/t/track-template-state-the-template-instance-scoped-reactive-way-instead-of-using-session-vars/3048

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [tracker](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker), either inside or outside a template. It will rerun as soon as one of its reactive dependency change.

Example outside of a template:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  //will be run only once when Session.get('callSayHi') is true
  if(Session.get('callSayHi') {//dependency on Session var
    sayHi();
    Session.set("callSayHi", false);
  }
});
```

Example inside a template:

```
Template.yourTemplate.onCreated(function(){
  this.autorun(function() {
    //will be run only once when Session.get('callSayHi') is true
    if(Session.get('callSayHi') {//dependency on Session var
      sayHi();
      Session.set("callSayHi", false);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: of course this can be improved by the use of something else than Session vars. Something like an object which handle multiples events stored in ReactiveVar